# Prove: $ \frac{1}{\sin 2x} + \frac{1}{\sin 4x } + \cdots + \frac{1 }{\sin 2^n x} = \cot x - \cot 2^n x $

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove 
>   $$ \frac{1}{\sin 2x} + \frac{1}{\sin 4x } + \cdots + \frac{1 }{\sin 2^n x} = \cot x - \cot 2^n x $$
>   where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x$ not a multiple of $\frac{ \pi }{2^k} $ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

**My try.** If $n=2$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sin 2x} + \frac{ 1}{\sin 4 x} &= \frac{1}{\sin 2x} + \frac{1}{2 \sin 2x \cos 2x } \\[6pt]
&= \frac{ 2 \cos 2x + 1 }{2 \sin 2x \cos 2x} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{2 \cos^2 x - 2 \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x + \sin^2 x}{2 \sin 2x \cos 2x} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{3 \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x}{2 \sin 2x \cos 2x}
\end{align}$$

but here I got stuck. I am on the right track? My goal is to ultimately use induction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skipping over the base case ($n=1$) for the moment, let's do the inductive step:  If we take the equation

$${1\over\sin2x}+{1\over\sin4x}+\cdots+{1\over\sin2^nx}=\cot x-\cot2^nx$$

and replace $x$ with $2x$, we get

$${1\over\sin4x}+{1\over\sin8x}+\cdots+{1\over\sin2^{n+1}x}=\cot2x-\cot2^{n+1}x$$

Adding $1/\sin2x$ to both sides now gives

$${1\over\sin2x}+{1\over\sin4x}+\cdots+{1\over\sin2^{n+1}x}={1\over\sin2x}+\cot2x-\cot2^{n+1}x$$

so, to complete the inductive step, it suffices to prove

$${1\over\sin2x}+\cot2x=\cot x$$

But this *is* the base case, just rewritten with the $\cot2x$ moved to the left hand side!  So let's prove it:

$$\begin{align}
{1\over\sin2x}+\cot2x&={1+\cos2x\over\sin2x}\\
&={1+(2\cos^2x-1)\over2\sin x\cos x}\\
&={\cos x\over\sin x}\\
&=\cot x
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Without Induction

We can werite series as $$\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{1}{\sin 2^{r}x} = \sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{\sin(2^{r}x-2^{r-1}x)}{\sin 2^{r-1}x\cdot \sin 2^{r}x} = \sum^{n}_{r=1}(\cot 2^{r-1}x-\cot 2^{r}x )$$

Now use Telescopic Sum

Answer (score 2):

Let $S_n$ be the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sin(2^kx)}$.
we want prove by induction that

$\forall n\geq1 \;\; S_n=cot(x)-cot(2^nx)$.

the formula is true for $n=1$.

let $n\geq1 : S_n true$.

we must prove that

$S_{n+1}-S_n=cot(2^nx)-cot(2^{n+1})$.

$cot(2^nx)-cot(2^{n+1}x)=$

$\frac{\cos(2^nx)}{\sin(2^nx)}-\frac{\cos(2^{n+1}x)}{2\sin(2^nx)\cos(2^nx)}=$

$\frac{1}{\sin(2^{n+1})}=S_{n+1}-S_n$.

using $\sin(2X)=2\sin(X)\cos(X)$

and

$\cos(2X)=2\cos^2(X)-1$.

thus

$\color{green}{S_{n+1}=S_n+cot(2^nx)-cot(2^{n+1})
=cot(x)-cot(2^{n+1})}$.

Comment: I am the first. do not change.

Answer (score 0):

$$\csc2A+\cot2A=\dfrac{1+\cos2A}{\sin2A}=\cot A$$

$$\iff\csc2A=\cot A-\cot 2A$$

Put $2A=2x,4x,8x,\cdots,2^nx$ and add

**See also**:  [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)